# Filter and Include don't work together as expected

Tags: javascript

So I have a clients that I'm iterating, then each client has some vehicles as an array represnted in strings, What I want to do is iterate the clients and check if a specific id is included in any of the .vehicles key, but I'm not getting the wanted results, check my function:

```
const v = clients.clients.filter((c) => {
  if (c.vehicles.includes(fields.customer) === true) return c;
});
```

Comment: What are “the wanted results”?

Comment: You should return a boolean in the filter

Comment: You should update your question with a sample of your input, and your expected output, as a [mcve] using the snippet `[<>]` tool in the edit menu.

Answer (score 1):

You're making it more complicated than needed. You need to return true or false inside filter so:

```
const v = clients.clients.filter((c) => 
   c.vehicles.includes(fields.customer)
);
```

Then you have a list of clients that have your values. At last your probably use a map to get an array with the desired results.

I'm guessing you want to have all vehicles so the next line is:

```
let vehicles = v.map(c => c.vehicles)
```

Comment: I don't need bolean rather the values that match.

Comment: @modih65067 That’s what [`filter`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) does already; that’s what it’s for.

Comment: I don't know which values but as said in the edit: Use a map to get the data you want from this Object. (I suppose you have an array of objects after the filter)

Comment: Also to clarify once more, you don't get true or false anywhere. You get a filtered list.

Answer (score 0):

An array filter callback should return a boolean, not the item itself

You can try this way

```js
const v = clients.clients.filter((c) => c.vehicles.includes(fields.customer));
```

Comment: Correct, but in this case, it’s equivalent. OP’s `filter` callback either returns an object (which is truthy) or `undefined` (which is falsy).

Comment: I don't need bolean rather the values that match.

Comment: You'll get the values in the filtered array but the filter needs to return true or false for each value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @modih65067 Yes, that’s what `filter` returns in the end.

Comment: Just to clarify a teeny-tiny technicality, `.filter()` returns an `Array`. So, if there are 3 items that match, then it will be an array of lenght 3. If only one matched, then array of length 1. Apologies for stating the most-obvious thing here.

Comment: Yes that's obvious. Indeed @modih65067 if you're looking for a single item you should consider using `Array.prototype.find` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put a new if condition in your filter.
The filter callback function takes the validation condition directly

```js
const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6) ;
```

As you can see above (cf [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) , the filter method will return a new array with only words that have more than 6 letters.

So, in your case, your function should be only

```js
const v = clients.clients.filter(c => c.vehicles.includes(fields.customer)) ;
```

Also, I think you need to be careful with the key name, here you have a **clients** key in an object that has the same name, it's not really understandable, maybe you can have `carFleet.clients`.

Comment: As I already said under the other answer, this is correct, but in this case, it’s equivalent. OP’s `filter` callback either returns an object (which is truthy) or `undefined` (which is falsy). So if the OP is “not getting the wanted results” with their approach, then this approach will also not get them the wanted results. The OP has yet to clarify what “the wanted results” are.

Comment: Hmmm maybe he just wants to add a key in his object if a vehicle contains a customer, so a map may be enough
```js
const v = clients.clients.map(c => {
    if (c.vehicles.includes(fields.customer)){
        return { ...c, hasCustomer: true }
    }
    return c
}
```
Will see with the return specification. Thx